# SearchAPI Autocomplete - Pass in contextual filter to alter query

Tags: 7

I'm trying to modify the Autocomplete module query with `hook_search_api_alter_query`. I would like to pass in the contextual filter of the page I embed the search in into the module so I can add it to the query. In a `hook_search_api_alter_query` function I wrote, I just used `arg(1)`, which works for the actual search, however when the autocomplete module runs, `var_dump(arg(1))` returns `Response Type: string(33)` followed by the autocomplete results and their html tags.

Is it possible to pass in the contextual filter into the autocomplete module so that I can use it , since the contextual filter has been changed to `/search_api_autocomplete/search_api_views_[view name]/-`?

My current query alter hook:

```
    function hook_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
      var_dump(arg(1));
        $prod_code = arg(1);
        $tid = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($prod_code);
        if (!empty($tid)) {
            $base_filter = $query->createFilter('AND');
            $or_filter = $query->createFilter('OR');
            while (!empty($tid)) {
                $or_filter->condition('field_prod_code', array_shift($tid)->tid);
            }
            $base_filter->filter($or_filter);
            $query->filter($base_filter);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that `arg(1)` within the autocomplete module isn't the taxonomy term, therefore the function doesn't go through the if statement. I need a way to get the contextual filter for the autocomplete function so that it can alter my query like it does when searching.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.
You could save your data in a session in `hook_init` or `hook_boot`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function hook_init() {
  $arg = arg();
  if (isset($arg[2]) && $arg[0] == 'taxonomy' && $arg[1] == 'term' && is_numeric($arg[2]) ) {
    $_SESSION['last_term'] = $arg[2];
  }
}
```